# How to getId using url dynamically in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to getId using url.But this code only get static urlKey.How to get urlKey dynamically using below code.....

```
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'bags')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);
            $id = $category->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
```

Comment: on which page do you want to get that Id?

Comment: Tamil ah iruntha....Please explain more in Tamil.

Comment: $parentId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->getIdBySku($sku);How to getId by url using this code